# SVN Repository size (including deleted file size)

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

How to get the sizes of all the files in the SVN repository,
Let us assume we commited 2 files (A and B) in the first revision with sizes 1 and 2 MB respectively.
On the 2nd revision we've updated A file and the size is increased to 5MB.
On the 3rd revision we've deleted the A file.

Now, how to find the complete Repository size (i.e.,file wise) including deleted files as well,
since deleted file (here 5 MB) will occupy some size in repository.

Answer (score 1):

SVN does not store all the content of a repository as a file at backend. Instead it stores the differences, rather than entire copies of file.

> Subversion stores changes as differences. It doesn't make complete copies of nodes; instead, it stores the latest revision as a full text, and previous revisions as a succession of reverse diffs (the word "diff" is used loosely here – for files, it means vdeltas, for directories, it means a format that expresses changes to directories).

From http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/subversion-design.html

However, you can still get the size of complete repository, which includes the metadata, changes/diffs stored, hooks etc. You can navigate to the root of the repository on the server side and get the size details.